# Building g++ via PHP: no build output

Tags: php, g++

I need to build a cgi file on a server.  Compiling a simple test c++ file is working ok.  The problem is I can not get get any build output, neither on success or failure.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$input = "test.c";
$output = "test.cgi";

//$cmd = "g++ --version";
$cmd = "g++ -g -Wall -O $input -o $output";

$retval = 0;
$errors = [];

exec($cmd, $errors, $retval);

foreach ($errors as $key => $line)
{
    echo "$key $line" . PHP_EOL;
}

echo (intval($retval) ? "ERROR" : "OK") . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

when I run "g++ --version" I do get output, but not when compiling.

The G++ version is from 2015

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting the error output to the standard output with `2>&1`:

```
$cmd = "g++ -g -Wall -O $input -o $output 2>&1";
```

You can also get the output as a string from `exec()` or `shell_exec()` by doing:

```
$output_message = exec($cmd, $errors, $retval);
```

Comment: Thanks, adding 2>&1 works.
I can't upvote unfortunately as I don't have enough reputation.