# PHP exec and shell_exec: no output

Tags: php, centos, g++

Yesterday I asked this question
[Building g++ via PHP: no build output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170656/building-g-via-php-no-build-output)

That part is solved, but now I now have a similar/related problem.

When I run the compiled executable (see other question) via my browser address bar, the output is printed to the browser window as expected.

However ,I want to use it within PHP and get the output via the return of the exec or shell_exec functions.  I have tried various things, including the following:

```
$output = "test.cgi";

echo shell_exec($output);

echo shell_exec("$output 2>&1");

echo system($output);
```

Nothing works..

Internally, the executable is c code, compiled by g++, and is using print_f.  That should output to STDOUT by default accoding to the specs, so I do not understand why this isn't working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you give any error when you run `echo shell_exec($output);`? can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, I found the solution:
exec needed an absolute path to the file